# Parse multi dimensional data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to parse the following string:

```
content = {
      "type": "formData",
      "data":"{
          "type":"text",
          "name":"FAMILY_NAME",
          "value":"nom famille"
      }"
}
```

I know i have  to use JSON.parse(), but when I do so I have the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 30
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: I don't think so... the problem comes from content.data.type I guess

Comment: Note: If the object is included in code (assigned to a variable), and not as characters within a string, then it isn't JSON. It's a JavaScript [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). JavaScript and JSON objects use similar appearance, but are not the same or used in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser is not very clear about errors when it encounters a problem with JSON syntax.

The problem is that you have put a quote after `"data":` which makes the JavaScript interpreter think that `data` will contain a string. But in the JSON format, you can't make multi-line strings, there must be inline. So it throws an error because it expects a closing quote `"` at the end of the 3rd line of your code. Also, you don't want `data` to contain a string but a sub-object.

A valid code would be :

```
content = {
  "type": "formData",
  "data": {
      "type":"text",
      "name":"FAMILY_NAME",
      "value":"nom famille"
  }
}
```

(I just removed the quotes at the beginning and end of the `data` field.)

Comment: I just figured it 5 minutes ago! Thanks anyway for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You added an extra set of quotes, it should be

```
content = {
  "type": "formData",
  "data":{
      "type":"text",
      "name":"FAMILY_NAME",
      "value":"nom famille"
  }
```

}

A quoted string is considered as text in JSON.

Comment: I just figured 5 minutes ago! Thanks anyway.